# Memory leak Due to uiimage in xamarin view controller

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a function that gets called  several times in a loop and returns a view controller( each view controller is like a slide of a presentation ). Uiviewcontroller has subviews like scroll view , uiwebview and uiimageview. As the number of view controllers increase, i get memory warnings and app crashes. I have wrapped the function in a nsautorelease pool and i am using "using" block to dispose the uiimages but no use.

Can you look at the code and tell me whats wrong and how i can solve the memory problem.

```cs
public UIViewController GetPage(int i){
        using (var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool ()) {
            UIViewController c = new UIViewController ();
            c.View.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, 1024, 743);
            UIScrollView scr = new UIScrollView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 1024, 743));
            scr.ContentSize = new SizeF (1024, 748);
                string contentDirectoryPath = // path string
                UIWebView asset = new UIWebView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 1024, 748));
                asset.ScalesPageToFit = true;
                UIScrollView scrl = new UIScrollView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 1024, 748));
                scrl.ContentSize = new SizeF (1024, 768);
                using (UIImageView imgView = new UIImageView (new RectangleF (0, 0, 1024, 748))) {

                    using (var img = UIImage.FromFile (contentDirectoryPath)) {
                        imgView.Image = img;
                        img.Dispose ();
                    }

                    //UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile (contentDirectoryPath);
                    //imgView.Image = img;
                    imgView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
                    float widthRatio = imgView.Bounds.Size.Width / imgView.Image.Size.Width;
                    float heightRatio = imgView.Bounds.Size.Height / imgView.Image.Size.Height;
                    float scale = Math.Min (widthRatio, heightRatio);
                    float imageWidth = scale * imgView.Image.Size.Width;
                    float imageHeight = scale * imgView.Image.Size.Height;
                    imgView.Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight);
                    scrl.AddSubview (imgView);
                    imgView.Center = imgView.Superview.Center;

                    imgView.Dispose ();
                }
                asset.AddSubview (scrl);
                scrl.Center = scrl.Superview.Center;

                asset.ScalesPageToFit = true;
                scr.AddSubview (asset);

                c.View.AddSubview (scr);
                scr.Center = scr.Superview.Center;
                return c;

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `NSAutoReleasePool` won't help you, neither will disposing the image or image view help you (In fact, your code disposes the `UIImageView` you're adding to the `UIScrollView` - I'm actually wondering why this is working at all).

If you are creating tons of instances of a `UIViewController` that hosts a lot of subviews and especially large images, you will eventually run out of memory as long as you reference these controllers from somewhere.

From what I see, your image is 1024x768, probably at 32bit color depth, that's 3 megabyte per image in memory.

You will have to get rid of the view controller's you're creating or make them smarter (load and dispose the images in `ViewWillAppear()` and `ViewWillDisappear()` for instance)

Answer (score 1):

The question is why are you creating multiple view controllers with the same view (different content)? Why not create a single view controller and then change the content of it on ViewDidLoad()? I don't see you using the passed integer anywhere so is this your actual code or just a sample of what you are doing?

If you want to change the content of the controller without reloading, create a function to change the values. For example:

`public void Bind(UIImage image)
   {
       this.imgView.Image = image;
   }`